# Получение всех похожих view. Android

Tags: java, android

Дано приложение где есть много одинаковых `view` и `button`,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где каждая кнопка `+` каждого `view` имеет свой уникальный `id`.Например `plus1` у первой, `plus2` у второй и т.д. Как мне в коде получить все элементы сразу, чтоб не писать для каждой кнпоки отдельно `ImageButton plus1 = findViewById(R.id.plus1);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
Resources res = getResources();
myButtons = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_VIEWS; i++) {
    myButtons.add((ImageButton)findViewById(res.getIdentifier("plus"+ String.valueOf(i+1), "id", getPackageName())));
}
```

Не знаю логику приложения, но мне кажется, что для удобства лучше вообще вынести view+button в отдельный класс `MyView` (например) и работать с `ArrayList<MyView>`: `.getView()`, `.getButton()` и т.п.

Comment: в общем, мне нужно получить эти плюсы чтобы повесить на них слушателей которые увеличивают поле с цифрами которое слева. Я думаю с вашим примером у меня это получится.

Comment: @Dmitry Похоже для вашей задачи проще использовать `RecyclerView` с базовым `view` в качестве `item` и с `ArrayList` кастомного класса.